# Searching for an article 

Tags: reference-request, bibliography

I'm searching for this article
C.VAN Winter, Mat. Fys. Skr. Dan. Vid. Selsk. 2, no.8 (1964)
Can someone help me?

Comment: That seems like a whole book (Theory of Finite Systems of Particles by Clasine van Winter, according to online records).

Answer (score 1):

it's a book, not an article; here you can [search for libraries](http://www.worldcat.org/title/theory-of-finite-systems-of-particles/oclc/504711130/editions?editionsView=true&referer=br) that have it (enter your location for the nearest library).

Answer (score 0):

It is for sale at [this book shop](http://xerxesbooks.com/search?author=van+winter&title=&key=&submit=Search%2521).